# Endless Application in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python script that I want always to run in the background. What the application does is that it goes to a Oracle database and checks if there is a message to be displayed to the user and if there is, use the pynotify to display a notification.

I tried using a Timer object but it only invoke the method after the selective time. I want it to invoke every time after the selective time.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  applicationName = "WEWE"
    # Initialization of the Notification library
  if not pynotify.init(applicationName):
   sys.exit(1)         

  t = threading.Timer(5.0, runWorks)
  t.start()
```

Will doing this work and is there a better way?

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
      applicationName = "WEEWRS"
        # Initialization of the Notification library
      if not pynotify.init(applicationName):
       sys.exit(1)         
      while True:
       t = threading.Timer(5.0, runWorks)
       t.start()
```

But that gave me another problem.

```
thread.error: can't start new thread

(r.py:12227): GLib-ERROR **: creating thread 'gdbus': Error creating thread: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Comment: I was answering just that before reading. Thats what you need, an event loop. However, I would use a variable an not True, so you can exit the loop in a clean way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem reducing the creation of strings. The below error -

```
thread.error: can't start new thread

(r.py:12227): GLib-ERROR **: creating thread 'gdbus': Error creating thread: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

comes when there is a lack of resources. Below is the corrected code.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  applicationName = "DSS POS"
  # Initialization of the Notification library
  if not pynotify.init(applicationName):
   sys.exit(1)         

  flagContinous = True
  timeout = 5
  # This loop will continously keep the application in the background
  while flagContinous:
   time.sleep(timeout)
   runWorks()
  # After 30 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed
```

I also used a lock file so that the script won't run multiple-times.

```
pid = str(os.getpid())
  pidfile = "/tmp/mydaemon.pid"

  # If we have a lock already block the program
  if os.path.isfile(pidfile):
    print "%s already exists, exiting" % pidfile
    sys.exit()
  else:
    file(pidfile, 'w').write(pid)
  # Do all the work
  applicationName = "DSS POS"
  # Initialization of the Notification library
  if not pynotify.init(applicationName):
   sys.exit(1)         

  # Controls for the application
  flagContinous = True
  timeout = 5
  # This loop will continously keep the application in the background
  while flagContinous:
   time.sleep(timeout)
   runWorks()
  # After 30 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed  

  # Release the file
  os.unlink(pidfile)
```

Comment: I was just writing up an answer that is identical to this one. I'm glad you found it on your own. One idea I had though was to make the `runWorks()` function return True or False to tell your loop whether to quit or not (though if you don't anticipate your program ever quitting deliberately, that's probably not important).

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to use this simple Daemon script:
http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/

It does a very good job !

Comment: It would be great if you could tell me how different it is from my code? Thanks

Comment: The 'os.fork()' makes the difference.